# Derivation, distr. of sum of continuous random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution

> Let $(X,Y)$ be a continuous 2-dimensional random variable with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. I want to derive the formula for $f_z(z)$, that is, the density function of $Z=X+Y$.

Let $\Omega=$$\{x,y : x+y<z\}$. Then:

$F(z):=P(Z<z)=P(X+Y<z)=\int \int_{\Omega}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$

Now, to get $f_z(z)$, we just need to evaluate $\frac{d}{dz}F(z)$. My problem is that i have no idea, from here on, how to get that:

$f_z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)dx$

I have tried change of variables with no success, still stuck on a double integral instead of a single one. Any ideas?

Haven't found anything on the internet either, so a link for the derivation would be helpful aswell. Thanks

\Edit: I'm only interested with the derivation starting with that approach. I'm familiar with the transformation theorem and how to derive this formula using it.

Comment: General formula: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_{a(z,x)}^{b(z,x)}f(x,y)dy=f(x,b(z,x))\frac{\partial b}{\partial z}(z,x)-f(x,a(z,x))\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}(z,x)$$ In your case, $b(z,x)=z-x$ hence $\partial b/\partial z=1$ and $a(z,x)=-\infty$ hence $\partial a/\partial z=0$, thus $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dy=f(x,z-x)$$ as desired.

Comment: Another approach, probably shorter: note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z}f_{X,Y}(x,y-x)dydx$$ and differentiate.

Comment: Amazing, thanks alot. You dont want make an answer instead? :)

Comment: Another suggestion: start from these comments if you like, and write an answer yourself.

Comment: Im fine, just wanted to give a vote up to you thats all.

Comment: Allow me to insist: writing an answer is an excellent way (the only real one?) to grasp the subject.